# pretty links .htaccess codes of a raw php blog

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need a help with blog which is in core php and want to create a pretty url using .htaccess

the main index.php which is a blog page and also post page which display a single blog post based on IF statements

so what I want to achieve is to make a visit to https://example.com/?slug=my-blogpost-url-slug
load as https://example.com/my-blogpost-url-slug

there's already an IF statement on example.com/index.php which check if there's an available post slug  and if not it redirect to 404

Already a visit to example.com loads example.com/index.php

below are the htaccess i code i have already

```
## force https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

## remove .php n co
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## remove www 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## error documents
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/err?code=404
ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/err?code=500
```

Answer (score 1):

> so what I want to achieve is to make a visit to `https://example.com/?slug=my-blogpost-url-slug` load as `https://example.com/my-blogpost-url-slug`

It's actually the other way round... the user visits `https://example.com/my-blogpost-url-slug` (and should be the target of your links) and it loads as if the request is for `https://example.com/index.php?slug=my-blogpost-url-slug` - which is the URL being rewritten to. Note that I've included `index.php` in the rewrite, otherwise you are dependent on mod_dir making an additional subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex` document.

This is called a front-controller *pattern*. `index.php` is the "front-controller".

> ```
> ## remove .php n co
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

But first, you need to "correct" your rule (above) that `## remove .php n co` to first check that the corresponding `.php` file exists before rewriting the request, otherwise this will conflict with the front-controller pattern that we need to write in the following section to rewrite your "pretty" URLs.

The "problem" with the above rule is that it rewrites anything that does not exist, which is basically what the front-controller needs to do.

The above should be written like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

You don't need to backslash escape literal dots when used inside regex character classes as they carry no special meaning in this context. The `NC` flag is redundant since the regex `^([^.]+)$` already matches both upper and lowercase letters.

#### The front-controller pattern

This is the bit you are really asking about...

We can avoid additional file system checks by restricting the regex that the rule matches against. ie. Just URLs of the form `/my-blogpost-url-slug` where the *slug* cannot contain slashes or dots (which would conflict with actual files).

You can do this with an additional rule at the end of your file:

```
# Rewrite "/<slug>" to "/index.php?slug=<slug>"
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+$ index.php?slug=$0 [L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Note there is no slash prefix on this URL-path. Include the `QSA` flag if you are expecting an additional query string on the requested URL.

When calling the document root (ie. homepage) then `index.php` is called (as you state), but the `slug` URL param will be omitted.

Note you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive multiple times in the file, as you have done. For readability, this should occur once at the top of the file.

#### Summary

The order of your rules is also incorrect. The canonical redirects should be first. For example, your rules should look like this (noting the additional points regarding the `ErrorDocument` directives below):

```
## error documents
ErrorDocument 404 /err.php
ErrorDocument 500 /err.php

RewriteEngine On

## force https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## remove www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## remove .php n co
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

#### FRONT-CONTROLLER ####
# Rewrite "/<slug>" to "/index.php?slug=<slug>"
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+$ index.php?slug=$0 [L]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/err?code=404
> ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/err?code=500
> ```

You should be using a root-relative URL-path in the `ErrorDocument` directive, not an absolute URL, as you have written here. This will trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect to the error document and the HTTP response status will be lost.

You should also be using the full filename, which I assume is `err.php` and not rely on your other rules for this.

You then don't need to pass the HTTP status code in the `code` URL parameter as this will be accessible in the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` superglobal in your PHP code.

So, this should be written as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /err.php
ErrorDocument 500 /err.php
```

NB: You are unlikely going to catch real 500 (Internal Server) errors having defined the `ErrorDocument` *late* in `.htaccess`.

The order of these directives in the `.htaccess` file does not really matter, however, it is more logical to define these first, at the top of the file, not at the end.

Comment: Thanks or the response and correction but still not working example.com/?slug=test should load via example.com/test or better still example.com/post/?slug=test should load to example.com/post/test

Comment: @zaacwiliam To clarify (as stated in my answer) you need to actually be linking to and requesting the "pretty" URL. ie. As in your question, this would be `example.com/test`. If you are currently linking to `/?slug=test` in your HTML source then you need to actually change your links - this is not something you do in `.htaccess`. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @zaacwiliam Are you perhaps changing an existing URL structure that has already been indexed by search engines or linked to by third parties, or is this a new site? If the former then you can implement an external redirect from the old to new URL, but otherwise this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @zaacwiliam I've updated my answer with more information and a complete summary of the `.htaccess` file, with the solution in place.

Comment: @zaacwiliam "or better still example.com/post/?slug=test should load to example.com/post/test" - You have your description/terminology back to front... `/post/test` would be the URL being requested (this is the "pretty" URL that your users see). This is then internally rewritten to the underlying file that actually handles the request. eg `/post/index.php?slug=test` (assuming `/post/index.php` exists as a physical file). `/post/index.php?slug=test` is entirely hidden from the user. But for this to be "hidden" it must not appear anywhere in the client-side HTML.